# Wii remotes won't sync to Wii

Tags: nintendo-wii, wiimote

My Wii remotes stopped syncing with my Wii. They work fine with the USB loader or homebrew but they un-sync when I try to use them with my Wii.
That is I can use USBloader or Homebrew and the remotes sync fine, the blue player one and player two lights lite respectively and can use the remote toselect things in list.  However if try to use the Wii menu or any wii game , I get the wii menu or game but the remote unsyncs and the remote blue lights start flashing a few seconds then turn off and wont resync.

I have tried a lot of the usual , unplug, change batteries, try to re sync, etc.
one suggestion is the cios is corrupted but which one and how to fix?

Comment: What exactly do you mean (what functions of the Wiimote don't work normally but work in Homebrew?)? Can you add a bit more context? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Looks like you have two unregistered accounts. If you register one of them, you can merge them see [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and that way you can edit your own questions

Answer (score 2):

Try to hold both sync buttons on the Wii and controller or unplug the Wii and replug it in after 5 minutes.